# Nginx rewrite first char host

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, host

There is a rule for htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([\w]{1})[\w.]+)$
RewriteRule ^root/(.*)$ site_link/%1/$1 [L]
```

It needs to be converted into a rule for Nginx.
And I know that **IF** is evil.

PS Thank you very much.

Comment: My version:

`
server_name j2 *.j2 "~^([\w]{1})+$";
set $char_host $1;
location /root/ {
    rewrite ^/root/(.*)$ /site_link/$char_host/$http_host/$1 break;
}
`

Comment: What's the point of the `([\w]{1})` part ?

Comment: XavierLucas, this select first char domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP Host regex is inappropriate.

Your are trying to somehow re-implement some domain name validation on server side while DNS won't in any way resolve a broken domain name format to your server IP.

Moreover your regex would let falsely formatted "domain names" go in if it was used : `[\w.]+` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+`, so you would allow a range of formats that are already rejected by DNS. See RFCs 1123, 2782 and 3696 for domain names format specifications.

So for this part : abandon the idea. Now, the answer is simple as you don't need any condition :

```
server {

    server_name my.domain.tld

    location / {
        rewrite ^/root/(.*)$ /site_link/$host/$1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. But you have not explained how to get the first letter of the domain.

Comment: @Sofia Why bother ? You are not even using it : your `%1` variable matches the whole regex. So that's the same than `$host`.